# Export csv from Microsoft Teams to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, cloud, microsoft-teams

I am receiving `csv` files from different users (from the same organisation) over `Microsoft Teams`. I have to download each file and import them into a `bucket` on `Google Cloud Storage`.

What would be the most efficient way to directly store those files directly into `Google Cloud Storage`  everytime I am receiving a file from a given user over Teams? Files must be imported using `Microsoft Teams`.

I was thinking to trigger from `Pub/Sub` using `Cloud Run` but I am a bit confused how to connect this with teams.

Comment: The real question is how to get the CSV file from teams? When you know, the rest will be easy!

Comment: Can you add more technical information about what you have already tried? specific tasks? To improve the quality of your question, please try to follow list "so in summary:" of answer: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Answer (score 2):

I imagine you should be able to do this fine using Power Automate, but it might depend on how you're receiving the files (for instance are users sending them 1-1 to you directly, or uploading them into a Files tab in a specific Team/Channel).

Here's an example template for moving files from OneDrive for Business to Google Drive, that sounds like it should help: https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/galleries/public/templates/02057296acac46e9923e8a842ab9911d/sync-onedrive-for-business-files-to-google-drive-files/